# Lua Pattern Matching: Get penultimate

Tags: lua

I have a string:

```
inString = 'first_second_third_fourth.xxx'
```

I want to extract the penultimate 'word' [where underscore is the word separator] in the first part [before the '.']

With sed, I would do something like:

```
echo $inString | sed -E 's/^.*_.*_(.*)_.*\.xxx$/\1/'
```

which I am sure is clumsy, but it works. How would I do the same with Lua?

Comment: The penultimate word is 'third', right?

Comment: Yes.  I have an answer that does the trick, but thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
print(inString:match(".+_(.-)_"))
```

A word that is not the last one appears between two `_` and so is found by `_(.-)_`. Note the match here is not greedy.

The pattern above greedily skips everything up to the last word that is not the last one.